# Error on Xamarin: only one operation can be active at a time, How to finish await on resume?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await

I have this error where I access to the gallery from my app, then I go to the phone's menu and select my app again, and when I try to access to my gallery again I get this error: only one operation can be active at a time.

This is the piece of code that I'm executing again:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions()
            {
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Large
            });
```

So what I want to do is close that activity or finish it when I go back to my app, so I can go to gallery. I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I'm kinda new with this. Please help :(

Comment: is this a runtime exception, an error on the console, or an error displayed in a system dialog to the user?

Comment: This is the complete message when I'm debugging the app tha is shown as a dialog:

Unhandled Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Only one operation can be active at a time.

When I'm not debugging, the app just crashes.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/598 Some user said that this error didn't happen in Production

Comment: try calling that method from Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: The thing is that I think I need to know when that await task is still running so i can close it and thus start it again

Comment: Hi Lucas. I can´t see where you say I might find a similar issue

Comment: Here is  a similar issue which maybe can help you https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/626

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Comment: No, KennyAli. As far as I can remember this was an ongoing issue of the library I was using to get images from the gallery. Just a matter of using another library